# Google Cloud DNS Quotas and Limitations

Tags: google-cloud-dns

We have started importing our DNS in to Google Cloud DNS and have run in to a 100 managed zone quota and 20 rr records per zone. I have enabled billing and the limitation remains.

According to this page: https://cloud.google.com/dns/quota

The quotas should be substantially higher.

Has anyone else experienced this? Will the quota go up once I have used up the remainder of the $300 credit even though we have enabled billing?

Any insight would be helpful! 
Thanks!

Kris

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to send this directly to Google.

Answer (score 0):

No, quota will not go up after you've used up the 300$ free trial credits. However, you may request additional quota [1] as you have already upgraded your account.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dns/quotas#requesting-additional-quota